# Invoke command-line mode in input waiting state

Tags: key-bindings

For example, I'd like to map `<leader>l` to enter command-line mode with a command (`AsyncRun` followed by a space) partially typed in, so that I can continue to type to complete the command.

So typing `<leader>l` will enter command-line mode with the following command waiting for further input:

```
:AsyncRun
```

And then typing `echo hello` will complete the full command and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> will execute it:

```
:AsyncRun echo hello
```

Is there any way to create a mapping like this?

Comment: 'Simple: `nnoremap <leader>l :AsyncRun ` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following normal mode mapping:

```
nnoremap <leader>l :AsyncRun<Space>
```

N.B. Instead of `<Space>`, you could just type a literal space character, but it's easier to see what the above is doing at a glance. If you wanted to *start* your `rhs` with a space, then using the `<Space>` notation is required. See `:help map_space_in_rhs`.

Answer (score 0):

You can request input form the user using `input(`.

```
        :if input("Coffee or beer? ") == "beer"
        :  echo "Cheers!"
        :endif
```

This supports arbitrary completion (see `:help input(`).

Alternatively, `inputlist(` will allow the user to select from a list of items, either by mouse or typing a number.

See also `inputdialog(` for a GUI alternative.